# How to query lazy loaded material tab using ViewChild

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to query a `MatPaginator` using `ViewChild`, it's located in a lazy loaded `mat-tab-group`, but I got `undefined`, even though if I invoked it after focusing on the target tab holding the element using `(selectedTabChange)`

Please have a look into this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwwz6o) element is in the third tab focus on it and check the console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using dynamic query so that Angular will update the query once paginator is loaded:

```
 @ViewChild("paginator", { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
                                   ^^^^^
```

And make sure you are invoking the query when the tab is selcted using `selectedTabChange`